# The image seems no so clear in openseadragon as its origin

Tags: openseadragon

I use openseadragon show arts in my web site, but they seem not so clear as its origin. (I do not have so much reputation to post snapshots):
The original one is sharper, and the one rendered by openseadragonone is blurred.

I was thought that it caused by Deep Zoom Composer, which decreased quality when creating DZI image parts, but i was wrong. The part image in DZI directory and the original one are exactly same, and all of them are readered by a browser(IE 10).

Now the reasonable explaination is the randering type of openseadragon cause the difference, is this a bug? or is there an option / argument which can improve rendering effect in openseadragon?

Comment: i post an issue on github, and 2 snapshot in it. [issue](https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues/646)

Answer (score 1):

Two possible issues here. Are you on an HDPI (i.e. "retina") screen? If so, there is a bug fix in master that's not on the latest release yet.

Otherwise, it's probably the minPixelRatio. By default OpenSeadragon allows the image to not be entirely full resolution at some zoom levels, to save on bandwidth. You can modify this value by passing `minPixelRatio: 1` as one of the options when you create your viewer (the default value is 0.5).

We can continue the discussion in the issue here: https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues/646